# Sumproduct in Excel VBA using function arguments as source

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA function that takes the function arguments as the source and then runs SQL commands on it. The SQL command I'm currently trying to implement as a first step is the equivalent of Excel's sumproduct() function, which in SQL would be something along the lines of "SELECT SUM(A * B)".

I modified some code from another site that used SQL to convert an Excel table into a single column, and modified it to calculate a sumproduct, but I'm having trouble converting the subroutine into a function.

Current working code:

```
Sub doSQL()


Dim strCon As String
Dim oneSQL As String

' refer to 'microsoft activex data objects library'
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object


Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
          "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"    ' HDR=No  means no headers (field names)


cn.Open strCon     ' open connection

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' F1, F2, F3 are the default fieldnames when no headers are included with data

oneSQL = "SELECT sum(F1 * F2) FROM [Sheet1$B:D] where F1 not like '' AND F2 not like ''"

rs.Open oneSQL, cn      ' get recordset


Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").ClearContents

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs     ' copy recordset to worksheet

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

rs.Close
cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing


End Sub
```

The end result is that cell A1 returns the equivalent of sumproduct(B3:B5,C3:C5).

My attempt to convert it into a function:

```
Function SQL_sumproduct(A As Variant, B As Variant) As Double


Dim strCon As String
Dim oneSQL As String

' refer to 'microsoft activex data objects library'
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
          "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"    ' HDR=No  means no headers (field names)


cn.Open strCon     ' open connection


oneSQL = "SELECT sum(A * B)"

rs.Open oneSQL, cn      ' get recordset

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").ClearContents

' Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs     ' copy recordset to worksheet

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL_sumproduct = rs

rs.Close
cn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing


End Function
```

I end up getting an error because the code does not recognise the function arguments A and B as a source.

Could anyone give me some guidance as to how the "Data Source" parameter can be modified to recognise the function arguments?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement in `oneSQL = "SELECT sum(A * B)"` is looking for fields named "A" and "B" (regardless of what is passed into the function in the parameters A and B). This is because A and B are enclosed in double-quotes.

To incorporate the parameters into the SQL statement, you would write this instead:

```
oneSQL = "SELECT sum(" & A & " * " & "B)"
```

Having A and B outside the double quotes causes them to be replaced with their values. `&` is the string concatenation operator which joins all of the pieces together.

Note: when dynamically constructing an SQL statement from any kind of external input, consider the possibility of SQL injection - see [here](https://xkcd.com/327/) and [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)